# Use Solr to search HTML Markup?

Tags: html, solr

Is it possible to use Solr to search within HTML files, e.g. crawl a Site?

Answer (score 1):

Solr is just the search index. Take a look at nutch for crawling the web.  http://nutch.apache.org/about.html solr will index HTML just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial#A4._Setup_Solr_for_search

> If all has gone to plan, we are now ready to search with
>   http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/. If you want to see the raw HTML
>   indexed by Solr, change the content field definition in schema.xml to: